# How to bind data to a gridview in mobile applications in .net

Tags: .net, mobile, mobile-website

I am developing a mobile Web application where I need to display data retrieved from database to a grid or datatable in .NET.

I have tried out with list but it is not serving my purpose as i need to display multiple columns and rows fetched from the database.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried outputting the data into a table? Tables are designed to display data in rows and columns in the way that you're after. Lists are designed for showing only one column (or row) of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to bind data to a gridview in mobile apps:
In .aspx page:

```
<mobile:Form id="Form1" runat="server" Paginate="true"  >    
        <mobile:DeviceSpecific ID="mobdevspec" Runat="Server" >
          <Choice Xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mobile/html32template">
            <HeaderTemplate>             
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>                   
            </HeaderTemplate>
          </Choice>
        </mobile:DeviceSpecific>
    </mobile:Form>
```

In .aspx.cs file:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)Form1.Controls[0].FindControl("gridview");
// gv.GridLines = true;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial      Catalog=sampleDB;User Id=orbtest; password=hyderabad");
con.Open();
string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM anderson";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
SqlDataAdapter adpa = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

adpa.Fill(dt);        

gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();
con.Close();
```